# BeautifulSoup: HTML Extracting Bullet points but not navigation bar

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup4 to do some HTML scraping.
I am trying to extract important info such as the title, meta data, paragraphs and listed information.

My issue is I can take the paragraphs like so:

```
def main():
    response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://ecir2019.org/industry-day/')
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features="html.parser")
    text = [e.get_text() for e in soup.find_all('p')]
    article = '\n'.join(text)


    print(article)

main()
```

But if my website link has bullet points in the body of text it would include the navigation bar. i.e. if i change `p` to `li` or `ul`

For example what I want to get as output is:

```
The Industry Day's objectives are three-fold:

The first objective is to present the state of the art in search and search-related areas, delivered as keynote talks by influential technical leaders from the search industry.
The second objective of the Industry Day is the presentation of interesting, novel and innovative ideas related to information retrieval.
Finally, we are looking forward to a highly-interactive discussion involving both industry and academia.
```

What I actually get:
`The Industry Day's objectives are three-fold:`

The tags in the HTML Source:

```
<p>The Industry Day's objectives are three-fold:</p>
<ol>
<li>The first objective is to present the state of the art in search and search-related areas, delivered as keynote talks by influential technical leaders from the search industry.</li>
<li>The second objective of the Industry Day is the presentation of interesting, novel and innovative ideas related to information retrieval.</li>
<li>Finally, we are looking forward to a highly-interactive discussion involving both industry and academia.</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Or css selector syntax so you can select the `li` elements as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ecir2019.org/industry-day/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('p, ol li')]

print(items)
```

---

Just that section:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ecir2019.org/industry-day/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.kg-card-markdown p:nth-of-type(2), .kg-card-markdown p:nth-of-type(2) + ol li')]

print(items)
```

---

The page appears to have changed so I am using a cached version (this will only work until cache is updated). You can limit to the post body with an additional class selector:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://ecir2019.org/industry-day'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.post-body p, .post-body ol li, .post-body ul li')]

print(items)
```

Comment: Thanks but lets say some of the text is within a `ul li`, `<ul>
<li>Short company portrait (~100 words)</li>` how would i get this too, since the navigation bar is inside a `ul li` too?

Comment: Extend the selector and add , ul li at the end  e.g. p, ol li, ul, li  ...tailor as required

Comment: But this still grabs the navigation bar lists too doesn't it?

Comment: My bottom one grabs only what you want as shown in question as example. To exclude the navigation use a not: pseudo selector to exclude that bar. Assuming you are using latest version of bs4. I will update when using computer again.

Comment: The page appears to have changed. With the cached google page I have restricted to post body with an additional selector. That seems to be fine.

Comment: Hi, I haven't had time to test this yet. Will test this over the weekend when I get back to my personal pc which contains the files. Thanks

Comment: No worries. Note my point about using google cache. If you don’t have an offline copy of the page and the cache has been update you may no longer have the same content to work with. I did test successfully with the google cache version.