# How to obtain bullet numbering from html using python/beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain the bullet numbers that is nested (1.1, 1.2, a., b., etc) from a webpage that looks like this:

1 Definitions
1.1 Abcdef.
1.2 Ghijkl:
a. abcd
b. efgh
c. etc...

The html code is below:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h3 style="padding-left: 43pt;text-indent: -36pt;text-align: justify;">Definition</h3>
        <p style="text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"><br /></p>
        <ol id="l3">
            <li>
                <p style="padding-left: 43pt;text-indent: -36pt;text-align: justify;">In this Notice:</p>
                <p style="text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"><br /></p>
                <ol id="l4">
                    <li>
                        <p style="padding-left: 7pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: justify;">Code of conduct.</p>
                        <p style="text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"><br /></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p style="padding-left: 7pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: justify;">The following:</p>
                        <p style="text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;"><br /></p>
                        <ol id="l5">
                            <li>
                                <p style="padding-left: 79pt;text-indent: -36pt;line-height: 16pt;text-align: left;">trains</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p style="padding-left: 79pt;text-indent: -36pt;text-align: left;">Buses</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p style="padding-left: 79pt;text-indent: -36pt;line-height: 16pt;text-align: left;">PLanes</p>
```

I have tried searching everywhere but not able to find an elegant solution. Tks!

--Update--

Adding the css  section which has the counter function which increments the bullets. I have a hunch that the possible solution should probably use this function. Thanks!

```
<style type="text/css">
#l1 {
            padding-left: 0pt;
            counter-reset: c1 1;
        }

        #l1>li>*:first-child:before {
            counter-increment: c1;
            content: counter(c1, decimal)" ";
            color: black;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }

        #l1>li:first-child>*:first-child:before {
            counter-increment: c1 0;
        }

        #l2 {
            padding-left: 0pt;
            counter-reset: c2 1;
        }

        #l2>li>*:first-child:before {
            counter-increment: c2;
            content: counter(c1, decimal)"."counter(c2, decimal)" ";
            color: black;
            font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 14pt;
        }

        #l2>li:first-child>*:first-child:before {
            counter-increment: c2 0;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to include the actual HTML?

Comment: What should desired output look like?

Comment: Look at this answer, on how to extract bullet points, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54672876/13005221